# how to extend existing Keycloak API resource in my SPI?

Tags: keycloak

I want to make an SPI that adds an API `/users/{userId}/mypath` under the user resource. But I can't just simply update `UserResource.java` to add my methods since my SPI should be plugged in as a wildfly module. How to extend `UserResource.java` in my SPI?